# How to handle deletes and their related aggregates?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

How should you handle the related aggregates if an aggregates gets flagged as deleted?

For example, let's say you have an article, that article has comments and those comments have comment replies and those replies have been liked.

If the article gets deleted

- should an event be created for every comment/reply/like to notify that these have been deleted?
- or should the article be flagged as deleted and then in the commandhandler do check that flag status if you want to create/update those comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your business rules and on your Aggregates design.

If the Comments and Likes are nested entities of the Article Aggregate then you should not yield additional XXXDeleted events for them as there is no need in the Aggregate for these events. If some command (for any nested entity) comes in the Aggregate afterwards then it knows that it (the Article) was deleted and it will reject it. The Read-models could be designed in such a way that, when the ArticleDeleted event comes, they will delete all its comments and likes as well.

If Comments are also Aggregates and you have some business rules that states that any comment from a deleted Article must also be deleted then you must send a DeleteComment command for each linked Comment. You can do this from a Saga/Process manager. In order to trace back why the Comments where deleted you should pass the Command ID as a Correlation ID in the Metadata of the DeleteComment command. The Read-models do not need special design as they will apply the CommentDeleted event as usual.